# How can I change the format date at this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

**Code JS:**

```
$( "#date_of_birth" ).blur(function() {
    if($('#date_of_birth').hasClass("valid"))
    {
        var str=$(this).val().split("/");
        var day_str=str[0];
        var month_str=str[1];
        var year_str=str[2];
        var calc= year_str + "-" + month_str + "-" + day_str;
        var birthDate = new Date(calc);
        var today = new Date();
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();

        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;
        }
        $('#age').val(age);

    }

});
```

Currently, the format to be introduced to make the calculation is as follows

```
23/09/1982
```

I want to be format

```
09/23/1992
```

Can you help me please change the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using jquery-ui

Comment: Using any `datepicker` plugin?

Comment: I guess you want to calculate age but using this format mm/dd/yyyy and not dd/mm/yyy .Just change the indexes code var day_str=str[1];
        var month_str=str[0]; .

Comment: Try this 


var date = new Date("2016-01-06T00:00:00+05:30");
day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)
m = date.getMonth()+1;
month = ("0" + m).slice(-2)
yr = date.getFullYear();
var formatted = day+"-"+month+"-"+yr;